# Linear Model, Identification of Structural Parameter

Tags: regression, linear-model, structural-equation-modeling, identifiability, marginal-effect

I'm reviewing the foundations of linear regression using Wooldridge's *Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data* and Cameron and Trivedi's *Microeconometrics : Methods and Applications*. The treatment with respect to identification of the classical linear model $y = X\beta + \varepsilon$ varies slightly:

1. Wooldridge states that $\beta$ (or rather the model itself) is identified when $\text E(X'X)^{-1}$ exists and $\text E(X'\varepsilon)=0$ (the population orthogonality condition is met). This allows us to uniquely define $\beta$ as a function of moments of observed data, $\beta=\text E(X'X)^{-1}\text E(X'y)$. In more technical verbiage, the mapping between the space of parameters $\beta$ and all possible model values is injective.
2. Cameron and Trivedi state that the aforementioned orthogonality is not sufficient and needs to be strengthened to $\text E(\varepsilon \mid X) = 0$ otherwise it may not be the case that $\text E(y \mid X) \neq X\beta $. This "ensures that $\beta$ is of intrinsic interest."

It's rather easy to come up with an example where $\beta$ is identified according to 1 but not 2 (just define a DGP where $\varepsilon$ is a nonlinear function of $X$).

I'm grappling with the different philosophies behind each approach. Are Cameron and Trivedi saying that what we really want to identify here is the marginal effect $\frac{\partial \text E(y\mid X)}{\partial X}$, which only coincides with $\beta$ when $\text E(\varepsilon \mid X) = 0$ holds? In other words, we need the structural linear model to coincide with the linear projection of $y$ onto $X$ (which describes a the joint density of $y$ and $X$ and has no inherent structural meaning)? This is opposed to Wooldridge who argues that $\beta$ may have some structural meaning in and of itself, perhaps derived from economic theory, that we care about (regardless of that coinciding with a marginal effect).

My understanding of this may also be muddled by an imperfect understanding of linear projection vs. linear regression.

I appreciate any thoughts and guidance!